# Moving django database - Duplicate entry errors

Tags: python, mysql, django

I'm trying to move my django database to another server. I followed those steps:

In my old database:

```
python manage.py dumpdata --natural --indent=2 --exclude=contenttypes --exclude=sessions.Session > dump.json
```

And in my new database:

```
python manage.py syncdb --noinput --no-initial-data
python manage.py migrate
python manage.py loaddata dump.json
```

at last command, i'm getting the following error:

```
django.db.utils.IntegrityError: Problem installing fixture '/Development/Projects/new-cms/dump.json': Could not load auth.Permission(pk=1): (1062, "Duplicate entry '2-add_logentry' for key 'content_type_id'")
```

My new database is fresh, empty database. How can i have duplicated entryies in it? / Any tips for solving this problem?

Comment: It might be because migrate have already created a permissions table if you have auth installed.

Comment: @Ivan Yes, i have auth installed. I also tried whole things wiothout 'migrate' command but error is still the same.